# How to check usage of 'it' parameter in lambda with Detekt custom rule?

Tags: android, kotlin, static-code-analysis, detekt

I want to write a Detekt rule which disallows usage of implicit "it" variable in a multi-line lambda. I've written method override `fun visitLambdaExpression(lambdaExpression: KtLambdaExpression)` but I don't know how

1. Check if the lambda contains 'it' variable. `lambdaExpression.valueParameters` contains nothing in that case.
2. Check if 'it' is used in the lambda.

And I've not found any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.CodeSmell
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.Config
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.Debt
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.Entity
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.Issue
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.Rule
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.Severity
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.psi.PsiWhiteSpace
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElement
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFunctionLiteral
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtNameReferenceExpression
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.psiUtil.allChildren

class NoItInMultilineLambda(config: Config = Config.empty) : Rule(config) {
    override val issue = Issue(
        id = "NoItInMultilineLambda",
        severity = Severity.Style,
        description = "Do not use 'it' in multiline lambda. Use an explicit parameter instead",
        debt = Debt(mins = 1),
    )

    override fun visitLambdaExpression(lambdaExpression: KtLambdaExpression) {
        super.visitLambdaExpression(lambdaExpression)
        val referenceExpression: KtNameReferenceExpression? = lambdaExpression.run {
            when {
                isMultiline() -> {
                    bodyExpression?.statements?.findKtNameReferenceExpression { ktNameReferenceExpression ->
                        ktNameReferenceExpression.getReferencedName() == "it"
                    }
                }
                else -> null
            }
        }

        if (referenceExpression != null) {
            report(
                CodeSmell(
                    issue = issue,
                    entity = Entity.from(referenceExpression),
                    message = "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
                )
            )
        }
    }

    private fun KtLambdaExpression.isMultiline(): Boolean {
        return children.filterIsInstance<KtFunctionLiteral>().firstOrNull()?.allChildren?.any { psiElement ->
            psiElement is PsiWhiteSpace && psiElement.textContains('\n')
        } ?: false
    }

    @Suppress("ReturnCount")
    private fun List<KtElement>.findKtNameReferenceExpression(
        predicate: (KtNameReferenceExpression) -> Boolean,
    ): KtNameReferenceExpression? {
        forEach { ktElement: KtElement ->
            when {
                ktElement is KtNameReferenceExpression && predicate(ktElement) -> return ktElement
                ktElement is KtLambdaExpression -> return null // Nested lambdas are handled automatically
                else -> {
                    val foundInChidren = ktElement.children.filterIsInstance<KtElement>()
                        .findKtNameReferenceExpression(predicate)

                    if (foundInChidren != null) {
                        return foundInChidren
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
import com.google.common.truth.Truth
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.test.lint
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

internal class NoItInMultilineLambdaTest {

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest0() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda { 
                        it
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest1() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda {
                        // Some good statement
                        val x = 0
                        test() 
                        it
                        it
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest2() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda {
                        // Some good statement
                        val x = 0
                        test() 
                        it.dec()
                        // Some good statement
                        val y = 0
                        test() 
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest3() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda {
                        // Some good statement
                        val x = 0
                        test() 
                        it += 1
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest4() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda {
                        // Some good statement
                        val x = 0
                        test() 
                        it.and(1)
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest6() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda {
                        // Some good statement
                        val x = 0
                        test() 
                        it == 0
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest5() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda {
                        funWithLambda {
                            it == 0
                        }           
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings.map { it.message }).contains(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest7() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda {
                        funWithLambda {
                            // Some good statement
                            val x = 0
                            test() 
                            it == 0
                            // Some good statement
                            val x = 0
                            test() 
                        }           
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings.map { it.message }).contains(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest8() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test(i: Int) {
                    funWithLambda {
                        test(it) 
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest9() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test(a: Boolean, i: Int, c: Float) {
                    funWithLambda {
                        test(false, it, 1.0f) 
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest15() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    var x: Int = 0

                    funWithLambda {
                        x = it
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(1)
        Truth.assertThat(findings[0].message).isEqualTo(
            "Usage of 'it' in multiline lambda",
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest10() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test(a: Boolean, i: Int, c: Float) {
                    funWithLambda { it }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(0)
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest11() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test(a: Boolean, i: Int, c: Float) {
                    funWithLambda { funWithLambda { it } }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(0)
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest12() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test(a: Boolean, i: Int, c: Float) {
                    funWithLambda { funWithLambda { it == 0 } }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(0)
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest13() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test(a: Boolean, i: Int, c: Float) {
                    funWithLambda { funWithLambda { it += 1 } }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(0)
    }

    @Test
    fun noItInMultilineLambdaTest16() {
        val findings = NoItInMultilineLambda().lint(
            """
                fun funWithLambda1(lambda: () -> Unit) { }
                fun funWithLambda(lambda: (param: Int) -> Unit) { }
                
                fun test() {
                    funWithLambda1 {
                        funWithLambda { it += 1 }
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
        Truth.assertThat(findings).hasSize(0)
    }
}
```